# Git clone not working in Qtest Launch - but it is working from my terminal

Tags: git, github, git-clone, qtest

I am using Qtest for running the scripts and it is running my local host

When i try to git clone from local host url...it is not working

**************Output***************

error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git clone https://@github.com/.git

Using this format it works..U can generate Personal access token in github->settings->developer settings